# Where is "VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" located

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2015

I have used Visual Studio 2013 before and I can find "**VS2013** x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts`。

However，after VS 2015 installation, I can only find `Build Notifications` under corresponding folder.

So, how can I launch **VS2015** x64 Native Tools Command Prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

For the Start Menu, it is located under `Visual Studio 2015 - > Visual Studio Tools -> Windows Desktop Command Prompts -> VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`.

However, the actual shortcut is `%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64` (at least on my setup).

Comment: I'm sorry to say that no Windows Desktop Command Prompts folder under "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2015\Visual Studio Tools"

Comment: I added this to my answer, but for me the shortcut points to `%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64`.

Comment: No vcvarsall.bat on the folder specified. Maybe I have missed something when I install VS2015? I just install it by default, no customization

Comment: Yes, that sounds likely. I went through a number of options setting things up. Unfortunately, I am not sure what you might need to do to install these, frankly. It's possible re-running the installer may help, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your time. May reinstalling is the right choice now.

Comment: You're welcome. Apologies I couldn't be more helpful. Good luck, regardless. =P

Answer (score 0):

Try searching in windows home search for  VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt. I found it today like this